# Make src/main/resources/ use the "flat view" like src/main/java in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e

Is there a way to make *all* my `src/main/resources/` folders have the "flat view" instead of the "tree view"?

I am using M2Eclipse which is excluding them (excludes `**`). Surely there's some way to just change the view option in the preferences instead of removing that from each project? Or is there an M2Eclipse setting that removes it?

Explanations of what I mean by tree and flat views below:

---

- Tree view

  ```
  v com
    v stackoverflow
      v example
          file1.xml
          file2.xml
        v weNeedToGoDeeper
            file3.xml
            file4.xml
        > someClosedFolder
  ```
- Flat view

  ```
  v com.stackoverflow.example
      file1.xml
      file2.xml
  v com.stackoverflow.example.weNeedToGoDeeper
      file3.xml
      file4.xml
  > com.stackoverflow.example.someClosedFolder
  ```

Comment: This is very annoying indeed. There is a dialog at http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/m2eclipse-adds-excluding-quot-quot-to-the-classpath-entries-for-resources-td136470.html that explains a bit of the background, but offers no solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new Maven project, m2eclipse adds an exclusion pattern to your build path configuration. You can make the folders flat if you change that.

```
Project properties
  Java Build Path
    Source tab 
      src/main/resources
        Excluded
         Edit
           Delete (or modify) exclusion pattern
```

Comment: I know I can do this. Is there a way to make it removed by default or to have the flat view even though they are not "source"?

Comment: I've just checked the maven source code and it looks like this exclusion pattern is hard-coded into the project creation. There might be other ways to change it but honestly I have no idea where to look. Your best shot is their mail list I think: [https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/m2e-users](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/m2e-users)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is the option you wanna change.

[image: Eclipse View]

Comment: Thanks, but that is enabled and the things that are included as source (`src/main/java/` and `src/test/java/`) are presented in flat view. What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way for folders not included as source to be listed as such.